# How to get Arxiv and journal link in citation

Tags: bibtex

Is there a way to auto-generate the code for the citation such that I get a hyperlink to the journal, to the Arxiv paper, or ideally, both automatically when applicable?

Now I am using the chrome extension "BibTex it!". However, the autogenerated code does not contain links. I could also use the code from Inspire, but same there the citation won't be clickable.

Ideally, I want something like in the picture below. [image] below:

Thanks in advance.

I use the following code:

```
@article{Hawking:2000kj,
author = "Hawking, S. W. and Hertog, T. and Reall, H. S.",
title = "{Brane new world}",
eprint = "hep-th/0003052",
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
reportNumber = "DAMTP-2000-25",
doi = "10.1103/PhysRevD.62.043501",
journal = "Phys. Rev. D",
volume = "62",
pages = "043501",
year = "2000"}
```

But nothing in this code is clickable. And I am not looking for a way to do this manually.

I read that one could change bibliography settings, maybe some setting could accomplish this?

Comment: Use `hyperref`, it will add hyperlinks to the ID of the papers.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Hyperref enables hyperlinks in my understanding, but I am looking for a way to autogenerate code for citation.

Comment: Hard to tell without any code, please show what you've got

Comment: Hi! See update. However, note that the question is how to obtain the code *NOT manually*.