# Hyperlinks using BibTex

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

If I get the citation code from a paper, from Inspire, it will look like this:

```
@article{Nezami:2021yaq,
author = "Nezami, Sepehr and Lin, Henry W. and Brown, Adam R. and Gharibyan, Hrant 
and Leichenauer, Stefan and Salton, Grant and Susskind, Leonard and Swingle, Brian 
and Walter, Michael",
title = "{Quantum Gravity in the Lab: Teleportation by Size and Traversable 
Wormholes, Part II}",
eprint = "2102.01064",
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
primaryClass = "quant-ph",
month = "2",
year = "2021"
}
```

Can I choose a bibliography style that would make the resulting reference clickable, to either the Journal or the Arxiv article? Or can I accomplish this in some other way?

In principle I could manually go in and ad a hyperlink but that is not very practical for hundreds of references.

When I start my bibliography section, this is the code I use:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{article}
```

But there will not be any links. Look for example at the picture below. There they have the Arxiv link. I don't know how they accomplished that.
[image]

Comment: Please make use to use the right tags, `biblatex` is not related to your question, your using plain `bibtex`. Additionally, please provide a full minimal example instead of sniplets like this as we have no idea which class or relevant packages you are using. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Can you make it clearer how this question is different from your earlier question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/599713/35864)? To me they appear to be very similar.

Comment: Anyway, the (perhaps disappointing) answer is: You need to use a bibliography style that produces these links (or you need to modify the style you are using currently to do so). `unsrt` is a very old style that predates the invention of the URL, so it is no surprise that it wouldn't show any links. `\bibliographystyle{unsrturl}` would be a style that produces links (not in exactly the same form as in your screenshot, but nevertheless).

Comment: If the screenshot is from a paper that is on the arXiv you can download the source and try to find out which bibliography style the authors used.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your answers. The problem is that I don't know latex well enough to explain it very well. I thought it would be a trivial answer just stating which bibliography styles have links. I could not find a helpful list namly. But now I realized it seems to be rare and complicated to have links in references, to my surprise.